# why is getchar() returning garbage values?

Tags: c

So I'm trying to get input into my c code but I keep on getting garbage when I use getchar().

I've tried using scanf() instead but no luck.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    int c;
    while((c=getchar()) != EOF){
        printf("%d", c); 
   }
}
```

I compile it on a bash shell with a text file as input and the values don't match at all. 
my input

```
lo
hello, world
23
```

my output

```
lo
108
111
10
104
101
108
108
111
44
32
119
111
114
108
100
10
50
51
10
10
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: You're printing the characters as *`%d`ecimal numbers*  instead of printing them as `%c`haracters

Comment: Other than the "lo" at the beginning (which I assume is a typo, I don't see how that code could possibly output anything that isn't an integer), that output looks okay to me? What specifically is wrong with it or which output did you expect instead?

Comment: The `10`s are linefeed from the **Enter** key. You seem to enter one, or more characters, and press **Enter** and carry on. Function `getchar()` reads every (non-modifier) key press.

Comment: The problem with your question is that you're telling the *input*, providing a minimal, verifiable, correct example... *and* providing the actual output. But you're never stating what is the **expected output**.

Comment: Look up an ASCII table and it should be obvious what those numbers are.

Comment: I see, I've got it working now. I wasn't understanding it, thanks for the help. I was looking to get as an output whatever the input was, I just wanted to make sure that I was able to read input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code outputs the numerical code that corresponds to each character your code reads in. Presumably, those are the numerical codes your computer uses to represent the characters you input.

You don't say what you expected or why, but it would have to be a series of integers since that's all your code can possibly output.

Answer (score -1):

`getchar`, as its name says, gets a `char`. You can store it in an `int`, but when you print it, you need to treat it as a char. Try `"%c"` in the `printf` format string, and it will work.

Comment: the return value of `getchar` **is an `int` and must be stored it into an `int`**